# display product filters with Woof in Dokan vendor store page

Tags: php, dokan

recently i was working on how to display correct product filters (with woof plugin) in Dokan vendor store page, but i couldn't find any solution.
here is what i tried and didn't work:

```
function woof_modify_query( $query ) {
  
  // Check we're on a /shop page before filtering the product query.
  if( dokan_is_store_page() ) {
    
    $store_user = dokan()->vendor->get( get_query_var( 'author' ) );
    $query['woof_author'] = $store_user->id;

    return $query;

  }

}
add_action( 'woof_products_query', __NAMESPACE__.'woof_modify_query' );
```

The problem is with woof plugin everything works perfect in woocommerce, but in vendor store page woof displays all existed woocommerce filters and not that vendors product filters, so my customer when checks a filter it returns empty page.

Comment: hi Alireza, did you found any solution for this?

Comment: @bravonet please visit this link:    https://wordpress.org/support/topic/woof-and-dokan-vendor-shop-page/#post-13057166

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this working.

Probably isn't the best solution, but here it is:
First we check if there is a url match (url of vendor store page),
If there is, add an action and a filter

the action grabs the vendor id of the current vendor store page and stores it in session data. The filter prepopulates the author filter in woof by the value of the current vendor.

Works fine except for the price filter (largest value is taken from all products in that category, including products from other vendors).

```
    //Build URL : Check if http or https
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on')   
     $url = "https://";   
else  
     $url = "http://";   
//Build URL :  Append the host(domain name, ip) to the URL.   
$url.= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];   

//Build URL :  Append the requested resource location to the URL   
$url.= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];    
  
//Check for vendor store url, Add action and filter if URL matches  
if (strpos($url, "yourdomain.com/vendor")!==false){

    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'grabvendorid' );
    add_filter('woof_get_request_data', 'my_woof_get_request_data');
    
function grabvendorid(){

$store_user = dokan()->vendor->get( get_query_var( 'author' ) );
$vendor_id = $store_user->get_id();
$_SESSION['storeid'] = $vendor_id ;
}
    
function my_woof_get_request_data($request){
$request['woof_author'] = $_SESSION['storeid'];
return $request;
}

}
```